# Bottom of iPhone screen unresponsive

Tags: iphone, multi-touch, damage

The screen of my iPhone 6 suddenly stopped responding to any touches registered below the middle of the screen. I can still use the home button and the other buttons, but the lower half of the screen is totally unresponsive. I had just gotten the phone slightly wet and am concerned that I may have damaged the hardware somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several causes for behavior like this, but in this case, the fix was really simple. My phone has a two-piece Anker protective case in which the front part covers the entirety of the screen, much like a screen protector. Some of the water got between the front of my phone case and the screen and was screwing up the touch screen responsiveness. All I needed to do was remove the phone case, wipe the water off of the front of the screen with my sleeve, and voila! Good as new. This has happened to me before but I forgot about it, so here is the fix for anyone else with this simple problem.